# Angular 2, How console the object object or loop through object object

Tags: wordpress, api, angular

I am pulling the api from http://ecommerce-ux.london/wp-json/wp-api-menus/v2/menus/2  and it seem to have everything setup correctly and now would like to display from the api object.items ( that is the menu children)
When I do  {{ menus  }}  I get [object object].

Apparently you can not use *ngFor if it is an object, so I needed to creat a pipe but still can figure out how to display the elements as all I get Keys or values.

Could someone please tell me where I gone wrong.

main-menu.component.html

```
<ul>   

    <li *ngFor="let menu of menus  | menu">
        {{ menu.key }} {{ menu.value }}

        <ul> 
            <li *ngFor="let items of menu | menu">
                {{ items.key  }}

            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

menu.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Menu } from './menu';

@Injectable()
export class MenuService {

  private _wpMenuBase = "http://ecommerce-ux.london/wp-json/wp-api-menus/v2/";

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getPosts(): Observable<Menu[]> {

      return this.http
        .get(this._wpMenuBase + 'menus/2')
        .map((res: Response) => res.json());

  }



}
```

main-menu.components.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Menu } from '../menu';
import { MenuService } from '../menu.service';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main-menu',
  templateUrl: './main-menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main-menu.component.css'],
  providers: [MenuService]
})
export class MainMenuComponent implements OnInit {

  menus: Menu[];

  constructor( private menuService: MenuService, private router: Router ) { }

  getPosts(){

  this.menuService 
     .getPosts()
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.menus = res;
      });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getPosts();

  }



}
```

menu.ts

```
export class Menu {
}
```

JSON

```
{
    "ID":2,
    "name":"Main menu","slug":"main-menu",
    "description":"","count":2,
    "items":[
        {
            "id":4,"order":1,"parent":0,
            "title":"Sample Page","url":"http:\/\/ecommerce-ux.london\/sample-page\/","attr":"","target":"","classes":"","xfn":"","description":"","object_id":2,"object":"page",
            "object_slug":"sample-page",
            "type":"post_type",
            "type_label":"Page"},
        {
            "id":7,
            "order":2,
            "parent":0,"title":"other page","url":"http:\/\/ecommerce-ux.london\/other-page\/","attr":"",
            "target":"","classes":"","xfn":"",
            "description":"",
            "object_id":5,"object":"page","object_slug":"other-page","type":"post_type","type_label":"Page"}
        ],
    "meta":
    {
        "links":
            {
                "collection":"http:\/\/ecommerce-ux.london\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/menus\/",
                "self":"http:\/\/ecommerce-ux.london\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/menus\/2"
            }
    }
}
```

menu.pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'menu'
})
export class MenuPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value, args:string[]) : any {
    let keys = [];
    for (let key in value) {
      keys.push({key: key, value: value[key]});
    }
    return keys;
  }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a pipe in this case. The answer provided by Robin had a slight error in the inner iteration: `<li *ngFor="let menuItem of menu">`, you need to specify that the `items` is a subarray of `menu`:

```
<li *ngFor="let menuItem of menu.items">
```

So your html should look like this:

```
<div>
  <h2>{{menu.name}}</h2>
  <div *ngFor="let menuItem of menu.items">
    <a href="{{menuItem.url}}">{{menuItem.url}}</a><br>
    <strong> Name: </strong> {{menuItem.id}}<br>
    <strong> Title: </strong> {{menuItem.title}}<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a [**demo plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/W4Zryl4FKiMgGTJLteEH?p=preview) :)

Comment: Both version give me an error:
First one give me.; Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'Main menu'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
and the second one
Error in ./MainMenuComponent class MainMenuComponent - inline template:11:7 caused by: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'self.context.menu.items')
Why you did use the api that I provided?

Comment: Yeah, the first version would give you an error. I did not notice that you actually provided the url with response, so I removed that one option. It should work with what I provided, as you can see the response in the plunker is exactly the same as you pull from your api. Since in plunker you are not allowed to make any other than https request, I made you a mock backend with mockable with the EXACT response, and you can see it works fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/7q0hjQPRzv94PWyaV7Lb?p=preview There has to be some other error in your code, else than you provided :)

Comment: As you can see here https://demo5426168.mockable.io/so_test I created the exact same response. That circular error suggests something else is going on. Self context errors points that you are trying to refer to the some variable itself from itself. The circular error is not present when you use the pipe, since then it does not point to itself anymore. So somewhere else in your code you are having some bug :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you can't ngfor through object object. The way you do it is via filter. Now in the end I created my own pipe, or so call filter. Not sure if it is right, but it worked like a charm.

main-menu.component.html

```
 <ul>   
        <li *ngFor="let menu of menus  | menu">
            <a href="{{ menu.menuitem.url }}">
               <strong> Name :</strong> {{ menu.menuitem.id }}  | 
               <strong> Title :</strong>  {{ menu.menuitem.title }} <br />
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

PIPE

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'menu'
})
export class MenuPipe implements PipeTransform {


  transform(value, args:string[]) : any {
     //return value.filter( item => value[item] != value[item]);

    let keys = [];
    for (let key in value) {
     if(key == 'items'){
         for (let a in value[key]) {
            keys.push({menuitem: value[key][a]});
            // keys.push({menuName: value[key][a].id, menuName: value[key][a].title});
            // console.log(value[key][a].id);
         }

        //keys.push({key: key, value: value[key]});
      }
    }
    console.log(keys);
    return keys;

  }

}
```